# Python: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, scikit-learn

I'm reading a bunch of RTF files into python strings.
On SOME texts, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "11.08.py", line 47, in <module>
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform(texts)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line
716, in fit_transform
    X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).fit_transform(raw_documents)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line
398, in fit_transform
    term_count_current = Counter(analyze(doc))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line
313, in <lambda>
    tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line
224, in decode
    doc = doc.decode(self.charset, self.charset_error)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 462: invalid
 start byte
```

I've tried:

1. Copying and pasting the text of the files to new files
2. saving the rtf files as txt files
3. Openin the txt files in Notepad++ and choosing 'convert to utf-8' and also setting the encoding to utf-8
4. Opening the files with Microsoft Word and saving them as new files

Nothing works. Any ideas?

It's probably not related, but here's the code incase you are wondering:

```
f = open(dir+location, "r")
doc = Rtf15Reader.read(f)
t = PlaintextWriter.write(doc).getvalue()
texts.append(t)
f.close()
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5, stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(texts)
```

Comment: try `X = vectorizer.fit_transform(texts.encode('utf-8'))`, if I remember correctly, I always mess up when to use .encode() en .decode(), just try one and see what happens...

Comment: doesn't work. I think it's a problem with the actual file.

Comment: try this but I'm not sure it works. string = ''.join( [chr(ord(i)) for i in string])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as I said on the mailinglist, it is probably easiest to use the `charset_error` option and set it to `ignore`.
If the file is actually utf-16, you can also set the charset to utf-16 in the Vectorizer.
See the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer).

Comment: It's better to be aware of the charset of the document corpus and pass that explicitly to the `TfidfVectorizer` class so as to avoid silent decoding errors that might results in bad classification accuracy in the end.

Answer (score 10):

This will solve your issues:

```
import codecs

f = codecs.open(dir+location, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
txt = f.read()
```

from that moment txt is in unicode format and you can use it everywhere in your code.

If you want to generate UTF-8 files after your processing do:

```
f.write(txt.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: the new open() returns: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "11.08.py", line 41, in <module>
    t = f.read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py", line 671, in read
    return self.reader.read(size)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py", line 477, in read
    newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 1266: invali d start byte`

Answer (score 4):

You can dump the csv file rows in json file without any encoding error as follows:

```
json.dump(row,jsonfile, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep this line :

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(encoding='latin-1',sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5, stop_words='english')
```

encoding = 'latin-1' worked for me.